# How can $S_n=n$ for the series $S_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{7}{8}+\frac{15}{16}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-progressions

How can $S_n=n$ for the series $$S_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{7}{8}+\frac{15}{16}+\cdots$$

My try:

We can Re-write $S_n$ as

$$S_n=\frac{0+1}{2}+\frac{1+2}{2^2}+\frac{3+2^2}{2^3}+\frac{7+2^3}{2^4}+\cdots \frac{2^{n-1}-1+2^{n-1}}{2^n}$$

So we get

$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}+\frac{7}{2^4}+\cdots\right)$$

Hence

$$S_n=\frac{n}{2}+\frac{S_n}{2}$$

Hence

$$S_n=n$$

But the actual answer is entirely different. Whats wrong in my solution?

Comment: Could you please be more explicit about $S_n$? It looks like $S_n$ is equal to the full (divergent) series, when I think you're referring to the $n$th partial sum of the given series. Please put the final term on the end of your sums, so that we know they're not infinite series. Your second last step (after "So we get...") is confusing!

Comment: The $n$th partial sum doesn't equal $n$ though. For instance, if $n = 1$, $S_1 = \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is not quite correct because $S_n$ has terms from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}$, but with your adjusted value, the terms on the right are missing the last value of $S_n$. Thus, the appropriate expression is$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
S_n & = \frac{n}{2} + \frac{S_n - \frac{2^{n} - 1}{2^{n}}}{2} \\
2S_n & = n + S_n - \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{n}}\right) \\
2S_n & = n + S_n - 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n}} \\
S_n & = n - 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

As an alternate solution method, note you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
S_n & = \frac{2-1}{2} + \frac{4-1}{4} + \ldots + \frac{2^n-1}{2^n} \\
& = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + 1 - \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \\
& = (1 + 1 + \ldots + 1) - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^n}\right) \\
& = n - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1 - \frac{1}{2^n}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}}\right) \\
& = n - 1 + \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

As you can see, this matches the corrected version of your solution attempt.

You can also check a few values to confirm, e.g., $S_1 = \frac{1}{2}$, $S_2 = 1 + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{4} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4}$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Given:
$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{7}{8}+\frac{15}{16}+\cdots+a_n,$$
as pointed out by John Omielan, you are missing the first (or last) term:
$$S_n=\frac{\color{red}0+\color{blue}1}{2}+\frac{\color{red}1+\color{blue}2}{2^2}+\frac{\color{red}3+\color{blue}{2^2}}{2^3}+\frac{\color{red}7+\color{blue}{2^3}}{2^4}+\cdots +\underbrace{\frac{\color{red}{2^{n-1}-1}+\color{blue}{2^{n-1}}}{2^n}}_{a_n=\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}=\\
\left(\frac{\color{red}0}2+\frac{\color{red}1}{2^2}+\frac{\color{red}3}{2^3}+\frac{\color{red}7}{2^4}+\cdots +\frac{\color{red}{2^{n-1}-1}}{2^n}\right)+
\left(\frac{\color{blue}1}2+\frac{\color{blue}2}{2^2}+\frac{\color{blue}{2^2}}{2^3}+\frac{\color{blue}{2^4}}{2^4}+\cdots +\frac{\color{blue}{2^{n-1}}}{2^n}\right)=\\
\frac12
\left(\color{red}0+\frac{\color{red}1}{2}+\frac{\color{red}3}{2^2}+\frac{\color{red}7}{2^3}+\cdots +\frac{\color{red}{2^{n-1}-1}}{2^{n-1}}\right)+
\left(\frac{\color{blue}1}2+\frac{\color{blue}1}{2}+\frac{\color{blue}{1}}{2}+\frac{\color{blue}{1}}{2}+\cdots +\frac{\color{blue}{1}}{2}\right)=\\
\frac12(0+S_{n-1})+\frac12n=\\
\frac12(S_n-a_n)+\frac12n \Rightarrow \\
S_n=n-a_n=n-\frac{2^{n-1}-1+2^{n-1}}{2^n}=n-\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}=n-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=n-1+\frac1{2^n}.$$
You can prove by mathematical induction: $S_{n}=n-1+\frac1{2^n}$. Indeed:
$$S_n=\color{red}{S_{n-1}}+\color{blue}{a_n}=\color{red}{(n-1)-1+\frac1{2^{n-1}}}+\color{blue}{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}=\\
n-1+\frac{-2^n+2+2^n-1}{2^n}=n-1+\frac1{2^n}.$$